# Issues in uploading prestashop from local server to live server

Tags: php, url, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I am using prestashop 1.6.1.6. Everything works fine in localhost but when i uploaded to to my server

> http://cableandmedia.com/onlinestore/

I am not getting

> This site can’t be reached. 
>   cableandmedia’s server DNS address could not be found.

I have changed seo shop url as

[image: seo shop url screen shot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the shop domain to cableandmedia.com (Instead of cableandmedia).